# how can i detect language in laravel 5.1 api for validation error?

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5.1

I have a api in laravel and I want return validation errors in user's language. how can I specify language in laravel api?
for example response this :

```
 if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->getMessages(),
            ], 400);
        }
```

return best for each language. fa and en.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) create a middleware in App/Http/Middleware

localization.php

and write these in that:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;

/**
 * Class Localization
 *
 * @author  Mahmoud Zalt  <mahmoud@zalt.me>
 */
class Localization
{

    /**
     * Localization constructor.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Foundation\Application $app
     */
    public function __construct(Application $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // read the language from the request header
        $locale = $request->header('Content-Language');

        // if the header is missed
        if(!$locale){
            // take the default local language
            $locale = $this->app->config->get('app.locale');
        }

        // check the languages defined is supported
        if (!array_key_exists($locale, $this->app->config->get('app.supported_languages'))) {
            // respond with error
            return abort(403, 'Language not supported.');
        }

        // set the local language
        $this->app->setLocale($locale);

        // get the response after the request is done
        $response = $next($request);

        // set Content Languages header in the response
        $response->headers->set('Content-Language', $locale);

        // return the response
        return $response;
    }
}
```

2) Register the middleware in the Middlewares
for this. go to App\Http\Kernel.php
add in this array that there is in kernel file:

```
 protected $middleware = []
```

this one.

```
\App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class,
```

3) add this to the app.php in config dir

'supported_languages' => ['en' => 'English', 'fa' => 'persian'],

4) create language folder in the lang folder "resources/lang" for your language  (in this case it is [fa] next to [en]) and of course set your files there. for this question only copy validation.php file to your fa folder and change error text.

5) set the header "Content-Language" in your request to ([en] or [fa]).

Answer (score 1):

There is No need Of Doing All This 
You can Do this in your resources Folder
1)Laravel's localization features provide a convenient way to retrieve strings in various languages, allowing you to easily support multiple languages within your application. Language strings are stored in files within the resources/lang directory. Within this directory there should be a subdirectory for each language supported by the application
For step by step guide check this link : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/localization